# C# Disable the TAB key

Tags: c#, character, tabs

I have this code:

```
this.searchInput.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(this.inputKeypress);

private void Keypress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // If Tab has been pressed
    if(122 == (int)e.KeyChar)
    {
        switchTab(sTab);
        MessageBox.Show(sTab);
    }
}
```

What it does is that it sets focus to another element.
But, when the focus is set to a TextBox, and I press TAB, it just makes a tab in the TextBox, and does not set focus on the next element.

Anyone got an idea how can I make this work?

I've tried to set e.Handled = true; but that didn't work...

Comment: Is there any reason you are explicitly moving focus when tab is pressed rather than relying on the default mechanism and tab order?

Comment: I need to set tabindex to a panel, and i can't see any properties for doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried setting `AcceptsTab` on the `TextBox` to `false`?

Edit:

> yep. It does not work. Strange... It still tabulates in the textbox

That makes little sense. I ran a small test app, and the tab key only brings focus away from the `TextBox` when its `AcceptsTab` *and* `Multiline` properties are both `true`, regardless of an event handler being defined for `KeyPress`.

Are you sure some other code isn't setting `AcceptsTab` to `true`? If you are, does setting `Multiline` to `false` change the tab behaviour at all? Could you post more of your relevant code?

Comment: yep. It does not work. Strange...
It still tabulates in the textbox

Comment: ah, Multiline is set to false.
I'll set it to true and hope to see that it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Set the `AcceptsTab` property of the text box to `false`?

Comment: yep. It does not work. Strange...
It still tabulates in the textbox

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to create an instance of the control like so, and override the following methods:

```
using System.Windows.Forms

//optional namespace

public class NoTabTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys keyData)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.Tab:
                return true;
        }
        return base.IsInputKey(keyData);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) { e.Handled = true; e.SuppressKeyPress = true; }
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

Build the solution, then subsitute you're regular TextBox with the new one 'NoTabTextBox', by finding it under the user controls in toolbox.

This will capture the Tab key and force it to do nothing.